# Resizing images and performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, image, browser, resize

I have an image that is around 1200 x 400 (if I remember right), and is about 50kb in size. I use the image in a header for a website, but I constrict the height of the image to 100px in order to make it fit my header.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AFact.jpg" Height="100px" />
```

Is this a bad practice? Does it mean that the image is being downloaded in full to the client, and then the client's browser has to waste cpu to resize it? Would I be better off to scale the image down to the height that I want it at by using Photoshop?

Comment: Why not do it on the server? Install [this HttpModule](http://imageresizing.net), and change your code to `<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AFact.jpg?height=100" />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a bad practice? Does it mean
>   that the image is being downloaded in
>   full to the client, and then the
>   client's browser has to waste cpu to
>   resize it? Would I be better off to
>   scale the image down to the height
>   that I want it at by using Photoshop?

Yes to all your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes, yes!

Not only you download a big file and only display a small one. The browser is really lousy in scaling images. So it will look ugly, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Same as the others **yes** to your questions. You can use a tool like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to resize your images in a batch file.